# MapStruct Custom EnumTransformationStrategy

Tags: java, kotlin, mapstruct

I am a bit confused looking at the [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#custom-enum-transformation-strategy) on how to use a custom transformation strategy for enums. I am doing this in Kotlin, but a Java solution is fine too.

I am using 14.2

I have this

```kotlin
package org.mapstruct.custom.spi
import org.mapstruct.ap.spi.EnumTransformationStrategy

class StripLowerCaseEnumTransformationStrategy : EnumTransformationStrategy {
    companion object {
        const val NAME = "stripLowerCase"
    }

    override fun getStrategyName(): String {
        return NAME
    }

    override fun transform(value: String, configuration: String): String {
        return value.removePrefix(configuration).toLowerCase()
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it within my EnumMappers, it says it cannot be found. What step am I missing?

```kotlin
@Mapper
interface EnumMapper {
  @ValueMappings(
        ValueMapping(source = "UNRECOGNIZED", target = MappingConstants.NULL),
        ValueMapping(source = "PERSON_STATUS_INVALID", target = MappingConstants.NULL)
    )
  @EnumMapping(
        nameTransformationStrategy = StripLowerCaseEnumTransformationStrategy.NAME,
        configuration = "PERSON_STATUS_"
    )
  fun fromProto(status: PersonStatusProto): PersonStatus

  @InheritInverseConfiguration
  fun toProto(status: PersonStatus): PersonStatusProto
}
```

Here is the error: `error: There is no registered EnumTransformationStrategy for 'stripLowerCase'. Registered strategies are: prefix, stripPrefix, stripSuffix, suffix.`

I also have created the file `resources/META-INF/services/org.mapstruct.ap.spi.EnumTransformationStrategy` with the value `org.mapstruct.custom.spi.StripLowerCaseEnumTransformationStrategy`.

Here is also a picture of directory in case it is organized incorrectly:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the configured `EnumTransformationStrategy` is not used is because SPIs which are available only in the same compilation unit are not used.

In order for this to work you will need to move the implementation in a different module (not package) and make it available during the compilationl

An example for how this can be done with maven can be seen in [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/tree/master/integrationtest/src/test/resources/namingStrategyTest) integration test.

Note: I see that you are placing the `StripLowerCaseEnumTransformationStrategy` under the `org.mapstruct` package. I would advise not to use packages that you don't own for placing your code, otherwise you might have problems with split packages when running on the Java module path.